# Python Pandas fillna()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a large dataframe with values like:

```
Name  A  B  C  D  E  F  G # Coulmns
Matt  1  n  n  n  5  n  5  # rows
Jake  n  n  2  n  3  n  n
Paul  2  n  3  n  n  8  n
```

I just want to fill NA values with preceding values:
This is achieved by

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

This is forward fill method which gives me an output of:

```
Name  A  B  C  D  E  F  G # Coulmns
Matt  1  1  1  1  5  5  5  # rows
Jake  n  n  2  2  3  3  3
Paul  2  2  3  3  3  8  8
```

The problem is that i don't want it to go till end, just stop if there are no more values in the back. See Row 2, Jake it must stop at E since it doesn't have any value in the last column.
Desired output:

```
Name  A  B  C  D  E  F  G # Coulmns
Matt  1  1  1  1  5  5  5  # rows
Jake  n  n  2  2  3  n  n
Paul  2  2  3  3  8  8  n
```

Is there anyway to do this with pandas?

Code:

```
 for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i][1:].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

Comment: First row `Matt` is correct?

Comment: Sorry, Edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by first column
- replace `NaN`s by back filling and check `NaN`s by `isnull()`
- replace NaNs by forward filling and replace `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)
- last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for index to column

---

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
m = df.bfill(axis=1).isnull()
df = df.ffill(axis=1).mask(m)
print (df)
    Name    A    B    C    D    E    F    G
0    Matt  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
1    Jake  NaN  NaN  2.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
2    Paul  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  8.0  NaN
```

Comment: That is brilliant, Thanks!